# Как установить рандомную прозрачность в rgba-формате?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
(names[i] == 'Вы') ? ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)' : ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'
```

Comment: если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод `Math.random()`. Метод `toFixed()` определяет сколько знаков будет после запятой.

```js
var color = `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${Math.random().toFixed(2)})`;
console.log(color)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctx = {fillStyle: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, ' + Math.random().toFixed(2) + ')'};
console.log(ctx.fillStyle)
```